# Find $R^{-1}$P where P(x,y). Verify that it takes points on y=$\frac{2}{x}$ to points on $x^{2} - y^{2} = 4$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this question in my book and I have simply been unable to solve it.  Here is the question:

Find $R^{-1}$P where P corresponds to a generic point P(x,y). Verify that it takes points on curve y=$\frac{2}{x}$ to points on curve $x^{2} - y^{2} = 4$

Where R = $\begin{bmatrix}{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}} & -{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}\\{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}} & {\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}\end{bmatrix}$ and so $R^{-1}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} & {\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\\-{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} & {\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\end{bmatrix}$

My approach was to multiply $R^{-1}$ by $\begin{bmatrix}{x}\\{\frac{2}{x}}\end{bmatrix}$.  I would then get $\begin{bmatrix}{\frac{x^{2}+ {2}}{x\sqrt{2}}}\\ {\frac{-x^{2}+ {2}}{x\sqrt{2}}}\end{bmatrix}$ but I don't know where to go from here.
 Can someone please help me solve this or at least point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R$ is the matrix representing rotation by $45^0$ degrees counterclockwise (if you didn't know that, you can verify it by taking a look at how it transforms an arbitrary vector), so $R^{-1}$ is the same rotation, but clockwise. So $R^{-1}$ applied to the hyperbola $y=\frac{2}{x}$ is just a rotation of it $45^0$ degrees clockwise (here's visual confirmation below, red is the original curve, blue is the result).[image] As for algebraic confirmation, take your vector $\begin{bmatrix}{\frac{x^{2}+ {2}}{x\sqrt{2}}}\\ {\frac{-x^{2}+ {2}}{x\sqrt{2}}}\end{bmatrix}$ and just check that the square of the first coordinate minus the square of the second equals $4$ (basic algebra).

Comment: Thanks V.Ch.  I actually understand the geometric effect of the multiplcation (at least I was paying attention to something) but the algebra is what I don't get.  Typically in this book they are looking to work out the algebra so that you show the equation of the first curve multiplied by R inverse to get x^2 -y^2 = 4.  This is where I'm stuck.  Would you be able to help me with the algebra part?

Comment: $$(\frac{x^{2}+ {2}}{x\sqrt{2}})^2-(\frac{-x^{2}+ {2}}{x\sqrt{2}})^2=\frac{x^{4}+4x^2+4}{2x^2}-\frac{x^{4}-4x^2+4}{2x^2}=\frac{8x^2}{2x^2}=4$$

Comment: So the two coordinates of $\begin{bmatrix}{s}\\{t}\end{bmatrix}=R^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}{x}\\{y}\end{bmatrix}$ satisfy $s^2-t^2=4$ and since $R^{-1}$ is a bijective mapping of $\Bbb R^2$ (because it has an inverse, namely $R$ itself), the original hyperbola is mapped completely to the new one.